# Getting SEVERE: SAAJ0131: HeaderElements must be namespace qualified in citrus framework

Tags: java, cucumber, soapui, citrus-framework

when I add header in my citrus framework I am getting error

```
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.HeaderImpl addHeaderElement
SEVERE: SAAJ0131: HeaderElements must be namespace qualified
10:58:23,221 DEBUG t.TestContextFactory| Created new test context - using global variables: '{}'
10:58:23,221 DEBUG ns.CitrusAnnotations| Injecting Citrus framework instance on test class field 'citrus'
10:58:23,221 DEBUG CitrusDslAnnotations| Injecting test runner instance on test class field 'runner'

org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapHeaderException: Could not access header: HeaderElements must be namespace qualified; nested exception is com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: HeaderElements must be namespace qualified
```

I have added header like

```
runner.soap(a -> a.client(client).send().name("test").soapAction(operation_name).header("Authorization", "Bearer token").payload(new ClassPathResource(path + payload)));
```

can anyone help me. I am new to citrus

Answer (score 1):

By default SOAP headers in Citrus need to have a namespace set. Your header is a plain Http header and has no namespace.

Please use the special Http header prefix "citrus_http_" when setting the header name so Citrus knows that this is supposed to be a plain Http header. You would then use "citrus_http_Authorization"

Also see https://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/2.8.0/html/index.html#soap-http-mime-headers

Comment: Thank you @Christoph Deppisch for the replay. for more to elaborate I have added below------  
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:iaut="url">
   <soapenv:Header><ser:Transaction xmlns:ser="url"/></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      .
   . 
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

in the payload i am passing only the content present inside body. Soap envelope(soapenv:Envelope), header and body is added by citrus.
continue...

Comment: continue...

Coming to token I am able to generate a token and I need to pass that token in the http headers. I believe ican pass that token in the request like
".... .soapAction(operation_name).header("Authorization", "Bearer token").payload( ....." as i mentioned earlier.

Now when I do that I am geting that mentioned error. I assume i am not able to add namespace in the soapenv:Header.

how can I add namespace in the soapenv:Header

Comment: Authorization header is not going to the SOAP header. It goes as normal Http header. So please use the citrus_http_Authorization as header name as suggested